# AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I'm new to Apache2, and I'm trying to get Apache2 running on my local Linux (linux mint 17). When I try to: **sudo apache2**, it gives me following error:

> [Mon Jul 20 16:15:30.785526 2015] [core:warn] [pid 14221] AH00111:
>   Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined [Mon Jul 20
>   16:15:30.785602 2015] [core:warn] [pid 14221] AH00111: Config variable
>   ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined [Mon Jul 20 16:15:30.785618 2015]
>   [core:warn] [pid 14221] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is
>   not defined [Mon Jul 20 16:15:30.785627 2015] [core:warn] [pid 14221]
>   AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined [Mon Jul
>   20 16:15:30.785644 2015] [core:warn] [pid 14221] AH00111: Config
>   variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined [Mon Jul 20 16:15:30.787550
>   2015] [core:warn] [pid 14221:tid 140466817042304] AH00111: Config
>   variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined [Mon Jul 20 16:15:30.787686
>   2015] [core:warn] [pid 14221:tid 140466817042304] AH00111: Config
>   variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined [Mon Jul 20 16:15:30.787703
>   2015] [core:warn] [pid 14221:tid 140466817042304] AH00111: Config
>   variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined AH00526: Syntax error on
>   line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Invalid Mutex directory in
>   argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}

Then I searched some similar problem online and tried: **sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart**, it gave me:

- Restarting web server apache2
  AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Again, I tried to find solution online which is adding: **ServerName localhost** at the end of the **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

Now the **sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart** command works but the **sudo apache2** still gives same error.

Could anybody help me please?

Comment: According to this answer, your result is to be expected. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49109974/631764

Answer (score 1):

Via the following [thread](https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash/issues/387), try these commands that require the usage of "service":

```
sudo service apache2 status
sudo service apache2 start
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 0):

try: sudo service apache2 {command} where instead of the {}'s you enter one of the following options:

- start
- restart
- stop
- status