# Apache error: AH00526 Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} (Apache2 Ubuntu VPS Server))

Tags: apache, ubuntu, syntax-error, apache2, vps

Whenever I run `sudo apache2 -S` on my server it throws the following error:

```
[Sun Mar 04 16:17:22.303217 2018] [core:warn] [pid 31405] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Sun Mar 04 16:17:22.303414 2018] [core:warn] [pid 31405] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Sun Mar 04 16:17:22.303503 2018] [core:warn] [pid 31405] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Sun Mar 04 16:17:22.303577 2018] [core:warn] [pid 31405] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Sun Mar 04 16:17:22.303655 2018] [core:warn] [pid 31405] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Sun Mar 04 16:17:22.306324 2018] [core:warn] [pid 31405:tid 140656836052864] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

I've tried several things but it keeps giving me these errors... I made some adjustments to `apache2.conf` but that ended up not working so I reverted my changes, tried downloading the default `ennvar`didn't work

My `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file looks like this:

```
            # This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
            # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
            # See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
            # the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
            # hints.
            #
            #
            # Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
            # The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
            # upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
            # default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
            # virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
            # order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
            # possible.

            # It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
            # below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
            #
            #   /etc/apache2/
            #   |-- apache2.conf
            #   |   `--  ports.conf
            #   |-- mods-enabled
            #   |   |-- *.load
            #   |   `-- *.conf
            #   |-- conf-enabled
            #   |   `-- *.conf
            #   `-- sites-enabled
            #       `-- *.conf
            #
            #
            # * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
            #   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
            #   web server.
            #
            # * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
            #   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
            #   customized anytime.
            #
            # * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
            #   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
            #   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
            #   respectively.
            #
            #   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
            #   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
            #   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
            #   their respective man pages for detailed information.
            #
            # * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
            #   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
            #   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
            #   work with the default configuration.


            # Global configuration
            #

            #
            # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
            # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
            #
            # NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
            # mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
            # at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
            # you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
            #
            # Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
            #
            ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

            #
            # The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
            #
            Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

            #
            # PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
            # identification number when it starts.
            # This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
            #
            PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

            #
            # Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
            #
            Timeout 300

            #
            # KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
            # one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
            #
            KeepAlive On

            #
            # MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
            # during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
            # We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
            #
            MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

            #
            # KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
            # same client on the same connection.
            #
            KeepAliveTimeout 5


            # These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
            User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
            Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

            #
            # HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
            # e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
            # The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
            # had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
            # each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
            # nameserver.
            #
            HostnameLookups Off

            # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
            # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
            # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
            # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
            # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
            #
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

            #
            # LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
            # Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
            # error, crit, alert, emerg.
            # It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
            # "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
            #
            LogLevel warn

            # Include module configuration:
            IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
            IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

            # Include list of ports to listen on
            Include ports.conf


            # Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
            # not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
            # The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
            # the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
            # your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
            # access here, or in any related virtual host.
            <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all denied
            </Directory>

            <Directory /usr/share>
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
            </Directory>

            <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
            </Directory>

            #<Directory /srv/>
            #   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            #   AllowOverride None
            #   Require all granted
                IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
            #</Directory>




            # AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
            # for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
            # directive.
            #
            AccessFileName .htaccess

            #
            # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
            # viewed by Web clients.
            #
            <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
                Require all denied
            </FilesMatch>


            #
            # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
            # a CustomLog directive.
            #
            # These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
            # (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
            # requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
            # requests.
            #
            # Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
            # Use mod_remoteip instead.
            #
            LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
            LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
            LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
            LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
            LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

            # Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
            # see README.Debian for details.

            # Include generic snippets of statements
            IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

            # Include the virtual host configurations:
            IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

            # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

What could be the problem, what am I missing?

This post is a continuation of this post: [Virtualhost Apache on Ubuntu server not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49085166/virtualhost-apache-on-ubuntu-server-not-working)

**EDIT**

I added `export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX`, `export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data` and `export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data` to `envvars` and ran these commands `sudo service apache2 restart` and `# sudo apachectl -k start -S`. This gave me the following output:

```
      root@vps520749:~# sudo apachectl -k start -S
      VirtualHost configuration:
      *:80                   vps520749.ovh.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
      ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
      Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
      Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
      Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
      Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
      PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
      Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
      Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
      User: name="www-data" id=33
      Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Now once I run `sudo apache2 -S` this is my output:

```
    [Tue Mar 06 00:46:48.762674 2018] [core:warn] [pid 11162] AH00111: Config variab          le ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
    [Tue Mar 06 00:46:48.762883 2018] [core:warn] [pid 11162] AH00111: Config variab          le ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
    [Tue Mar 06 00:46:48.762967 2018] [core:warn] [pid 11162] AH00111: Config variab          le ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
    [Tue Mar 06 00:46:48.763091 2018] [core:warn] [pid 11162] AH00111: Config variab          le ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
    [Tue Mar 06 00:46:48.765580 2018] [core:warn] [pid 11162:tid 139874816681856] AH          00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
    [Tue Mar 06 00:46:48.765970 2018] [core:warn] [pid 11162:tid 139874816681856] AH          00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
    [Tue Mar 06 00:46:48.766049 2018] [core:warn] [pid 11162:tid 139874816681856] AH          00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
    AH00543: apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
```

Answer (score 1):

These messages are to be expected.
When Apache binary is invoked directly, it ignores contents of `/etc/apache2/envvars` file.
This will not occur if Apache is started via init file or `apachectl`.
Make sure that the variable is defined:

```
# grep lock /etc/apache2/envvars 
export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX
```

And use:

```
# sudo apachectl -k start -S
```

Comment: Okay I added the export `export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX`, `export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data` and `
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data` to `envvars`and did `sudo service apache2 restart` and then did `# sudo apachectl -k start -S`. But I still get errors I edited the question with the new errors

Comment: By running `sudo apache2 -S` you are once again invoking Apache binary without the configuration and variables.
Try checking this thread - https://serverfault.com/questions/558283/

Comment: So it's normal to get these error messages when running `sudo apache2 -S`?

Comment: Yep. That is what I am trying to say.
`These messages are to be expected. When Apache binary is invoked directly, it ignores contents of /etc/apache2/envvars file.`